# In Ember, AJAX callback should it be wrapped in Ember run loop?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, ember.js, callback

The below statement is [from ember guides](https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.13.0/applications/run-loop/),

> The most common case for using the run loop is integrating with a
>   non-Ember API that includes some sort of asynchronous callback. For
>   example:
>
> DOM update and event callbacks
>   setTimeout and setInterval callbacks
>   postMessage and messageChannel event handlers
>   **AJAX callbacks**
>   Websocket callbacks

I usually will do for AJAX request,

```
Ember.$.ajax(
{
 type: "POST",
 url:"someurl",
 contentType: "application/json",
 success: function(data) {
 //Should I wrap this success callback code in Run loop. or is it safe to leave
 //Here I will set properties to display, I might call sendAction/send to communicate with parent.
 }
})
```

I haven't faced any problem with that but sometime rendering is taking too much time after I change data in callback ?. does any one face that issue ?

**Should I use [ember-ajax addon](https://github.com/ember-cli/ember-ajax) to wrap success callback in Ember run loop?.**

PS: Below is [from ember guides](https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.13.0/applications/run-loop/#toc_what-happens-if-i-forget-to-start-a-run-loop-in-an-async-handler), 
you should wrap any non-Ember async callbacks in Ember.run. If you don't, Ember will try to approximate a beginning and end for you. Relying on autoruns is not a rigorous or efficient way to use the run loop.

Comment: i haven't been doing that with Ember.$.ajax and haven't noticed any issues. it certainly wouldn't hurt anything if you were to do that.

Comment: as far as I know Ember creates a run loop for you. you can check what I mean in the following [twiddle](https://ember-twiddle.com/50dadfba6b3c363204b658a2af156cf9?openFiles=tests.acceptance.simple-ajax-route-without-runloop-acceptance-test.js%2C&route=%2Fsimple-ajax-route-without-runloop). There are two identical routes, one with run loop and one without it. Since run loops in tests are automatically disabled; the one without run loop gives an error indicating it needs a run loop. However, in terms of application behavior nothing seems to be different. I personally do it when test complains.

Comment: Since Ember CLI 3.0, $.ajax not wrapped in Ember run loop will generate errors when building: `error  Don't use jQuery without Ember Run Loop  ember/jquery-ember-run`.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me. Basically, you just need to wrap the actions/callbacks in run.bind loop. https://github.com/ember-cli/eslint-plugin-ember/blob/master/docs/rules/jquery-ember-run.md

```
import $ from 'jquery';
import { bind } from '@ember/runloop';

$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url:"someurl",
  contentType: "application/json",
}).then(bind(this, (data) => {
  // Handle success here
});
```